# Django Serializer takes too much time to query

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have an API which is currently returning just returning 465 KB data but taking too long to process:

Here's an image of postman:

[image]

There are just 300 objects in the query and the views and serializers are like the following:

Views.py

```
class MaterialRequestListEmployeeAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EMaterialRequestListSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MaterialRequest.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MaterialRequestListEmployeeAPIView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset
```

Serializer.py

```
class EMaterialRequestFlowsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequestFlow
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1


class EMaterialRequestListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flows = EMaterialRequestFlowsListSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequest
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

Models.py

```
class MaterialRequestFlow(models.Model):

    flow = models.ForeignKey(Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class MaterialRequest(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
    flows = models.ManyToManyField(MaterialRequestFlow)
    is_allocated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivery_required_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    raised_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="__________", blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I increase the performance of the API?
I tried increasing the `instance` configuration on AWS but it had no effect on the retrieval time

Comment: At first, define what kind of data you need. `depth=1`, especially in the inner serializer can significantly slow down your request.

Comment: @Crosby I am using most of the data I am getting by using `depth`, I have tried using `slugrelatedfields` for some APIs but it's not possible in this case

Comment: As a first step you can use query indexing

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related


I recommend you to watch this video which explains it very well in my opinion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uoI6pvuvYs .


also try to take more control on the data that you return.
Avoid using ````fields = "__all__"```` in your serializer, which may cause you give unnecessary data.
remove ````depth=1```` as @Crosby mentioned and define objects by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to try and profile the code and establish where the bottleneck may lie.  But some pointers for you:

1. Avoid using "**all**" for fields, you might get data that's unneeded and slow (depending on what that data is) to serialize
2. Avoid using depth=1 ... this essentially is an extension of the above, as we cannot know what that's actually doing for your set of related models.  I've used DRF for a number of years, and have never used depth, preferring to specify which models should be serialized using what serializers
3. Use prefetch_related and select_related where possible

In this case, I would start with the following:

- Change the queryset variable of `MaterialRequestListEmployeeAPIView` to `MaterialRequest.objects.all().order_by('-id').prefetch_related('materialrequestflow_set')` (or whatever alias you have for that reverse relation
- Change fields on EMaterialRequestListSerializer to just `('id', 'flows')
- Change fields on EMaterialRequestFlowsListSerializer to just `('id', 'quantity')`
- (Get rid of your `get_queryset` method on the view, since it does nothing the parent class doesn't already do - optional, obviously wouldn't affect performance)

The first one, depending on your data, would have the largest impact, so feel free to try that in isolation first.

If that's no good, then do all the changes mentioned, and if it's still slow, then it would seem you have some sort of database problem.  If it's fast, then work back to include more fields (e.g. 'kit' on the 'EMaterialRequestFlowsListSerializer`) and try to find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any foreign keys exists in your model, then you need to call them in single db hit using select / prefetch related options, otherwise they will call for db for each foreign key in your model object.

In your case, in viewset please modify your queryset as:

```
MaterialRequest.objects.select_related(
    'owner'
).prefetch_related(
    'flows'
).all().order_by('-id')
```

You can read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/performance/